# Power supply and equipment that I should have to fit all small electronic projects

Tags: power-supply, voltage, motor, amperage

In the last 2 months I have been wasting money in power supplies, I have been learning a lot and spending a lot of hours every day with robots and electronics so I upgraded my motors and my projects accordingly, which also needs an upgrade on the power supply (I have a software development background so I could focus in learning only the electronic part of it).

I always find myself struggling with the power supply part of it and every time that I buy a new one in a couple of weeks it is not enough anymore, so my doubts are:

I understand that if I'm using 6 motors connected to the same power supply and every motor (for example) requires 6 volts and 2 amps I need a power supply that provides 6 volts and 12 amps (is my understanding correct?) so I assume that I need something like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/IPSXP-Adjustable-Switching-Regulated-Alligator/dp/B07JCRDYWX/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=15%20amp%20power%20supply&qid=1590962011&s=diy&sr=1-4) ? (I couldn't find another thing with 10+ amps but only 6-8 volts)

For what I understand you can have problems with too much voltage (you can fry the motor) but amps are ok as everything just takes what it needs?

What would you guys use if you have the intention of working in different projects that require different motors, voltages and amps, do you aim to buy something specific for every project or something that will work with anything? Or a combination of things? What would you guys recommend me to buy and always have in my "tool box" for this purpose?

Comment: think about it this way ... a 12 V automotive battery will start a vehicle engine because it is able to provide the necessary current ... eight AA cells, when connected in series, form a 12 V battery that is unable to start an engine because the produced current is insufficient ... both of them will light a 12 V light bulb without burning out the bulb .... so, if you get a 5 V, 200 A power supply, then you can use it to do all of your development, and buy low powered power supplies to run the finished projects when needed ... cont.

Comment: cont. ... of course, a power supply that can supply 200 A can vaporize wires if shorted, so a bench power supply with adjustable current limiting would be preferable

Comment: I think it is always important to have a current-limit feature for a voltage supply. It should work both ways, so you can set the current you want and establish the voltage compliance or you can set it the other way, as well. I also think it would be very nice to have a triple-output power supply, with two of them "tracking" each other (handy, but don't spend the money for it unwisely, either.) I have three of such supplies plus a variety of single supply "cheap" boxes. Consider the highest voltage you may need, too. Two of my "triples" limit out at 36 V and 1.5 A, with the 3rd at 6 V and 3 A.

Comment: Nothing works for everything - but something like a 0-20 or 0-30 V x 10A supply with variable voltage and variable current limit will meet most needs. That's not (usually) cheap - so you may wish to start with a lower voltage and/or current variable supply that works in many cases. Used power supplies from haptops can be very low cost and useful - eg 19VDC and up to 5A is common (19V at less is more common). You can build a variable voltage unit with an LM317 (1 to 2A max) or LM350 (3A+) or other with one of these as power source. Plus a LARGE heatsink.

Comment: There are low cost surplus supplies available | ebay & Aliexpress sell modules that allow you to build a cheap and reasonably effective power supply at reasonable cost. || Q1: Where are you located? (affects source and cost and ...) || Q2: What is your budget? || 4-40VDC in, 1.25-37V out, 2A $US1.53! [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-Buck-Step-Down-Converter-Module-LM2596-Voltage-Regulator-Led-Voltmeter-M3/353086858369?hash=item52359de481:g:0LwAAOSwY45UMfSP) :Many maybes [here](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=variable+voltage+buck+converter&_sacat=181993)

Comment: This is astoundingly cheap - sellers reputation is good but ??? [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-300W-20A-CC-CV-Adjustable-Step-Down-Voltage-Buck-Converter-Constant-Current/254036044723?hash=item3b25ba6bb3:m:mKKI8A0zOSDaIh85C_0qovw) Vin 6-10V, Vout 1.2-36V (and < Vin) 15A. || Add metering to suit .

Answer (score 1):

Based on the helpful comments I did understand a little better what I should be aiming for, what I ended up buying (will update this answer when everything is delivered and tested):

12v Volt 600W Power Supply Transformers Drivers Ac Dc Adapters ([this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B072M7P7QJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1)), so I can have a low voltage, high amp power supply.

also got a ANGEEK 300W 20A DC-DC Wandlermodul Step Down Voltage ([this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07RGWJHPZ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) so I can use the 12v power supply for things that require a lower voltage with an output of 20 amp (more than enough to cover my needs).

of course you will need a digital multimeter to make sure that everything is correct.